# Understanding the "last cached state" of NSManagedObject

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm reading the doc of [`refresh(_:mergeChanges:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506224-refresh) of `NSManagedObjectContext`.

> If flag is NO, then object is turned into a fault and any pending
>   changes are lost. The object remains a fault until it is accessed
>   again, at which time its property values will be reloaded from **the
>   store or last cached state**.
>
> If flag is YES, then object is turned into a fault and object’s property values are reloaded from the values from **the store or the
>   last cached state** then any changes that were made (in the local
>   context) are re-applied over those (now newly updated) values. (If
>   flag is YES the merge of the values into object will always succeed—in
>   this case there is therefore no such thing as a “merge conflict” or a
>   merge that is not possible.)

I have a `mainQueueConcurrencyType` typed `NSManagedObjectContext` as a Child of an `privateQueueConcurrencyType` one.

When I create objects in the private/parent one, even they are not saved, I can access them using `NSManagedObjectID` in the child context.

So in this case, **is the Parent Context the provider of "last cached state"**?

In the "one liner" description of `refresh(_:mergeChanges:)`, it only says

> Updates the persistent properties of a managed object to use the
>   latest values from the persistent store.

That's really confusing to me.

I've read the **Parent Store** section of [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext). So the child context doesn't use a coordinator. That conflicts with the `refresh(_:mergeChanges:)`'s statement, does it?

Comment: The doc should make it clear that a Parent Store is a Persistent Store when a context has a parent.